# PHP - Update array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

So I am trying to find the best way to do this. I have to import an XML feed with job entries and build/update a multidimensional array. This feed should be imported periodically and update the existing array I have. The feed may have updated values and as well as entries that have been deleted. I have looked into `array_replace` function which *does* replace the values but does not remove the non-existing entries.

Below is an example entry on the array

```
array(
    ["post_general"]=> array(
        ["ID"]=> 123
        ["post_content"]=> "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."
        ["post_title"]=> "QA LEAD"
        ["post_type"]=> "job_listing"
        ["filter"]=> "raw"
    )
    ["post_meta"]=> array(
        ["job_location"]=> "New York, NY"
        ["application"]=> "xxx://xxxxxx.xxx"
        ["job_expires"]=> "2017-01-11"
    )
)
```

Please let me know if there is anything unclear. I'm not very good at explaining things :)

Comment: If you want to map an xml to an array, you need to process it. Loop over the nodes and decide if update or delete.

Comment: I do process it using `simplexml_load_string` so that I get a PHP object array. I dont need all the data in the feed. So I kinda have to make my own array using the data I get from the feed.

Comment: I guess I would create a whitelist array `$importNodes = array('post_meta', 'job_location', '...')`. Then recursively iterating through the array containg all nodes as key. In case the key is not in the defined whitelist remove the key. Alternatively a blacklist could be created.

Comment: sorry, i don't quite understand about your problem. but maybe you can try this: create `$array = array ( ... your array ... );` and simple to change the value. example '$array['post_general']['ID']=12345;`.